# Alexa Skill output image and text side by side

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am using APL version 1.6 and have already added a background, header, text, image and footer.
I fail to insert the image centered on the left side and the text centered on the right side. It is always done one below the other.

Here is my output so far:

```
{
  "type": "APL",
  "version": "1.6",
  "theme": "dark",
  "styles": {
  },  
  "import": [
    {
      "name": "alexa-layouts",
      "version": "1.3.0"
    }
  ],
  "mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
      "StationData"
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "Container",
        "height": "100vh",
        "width": "100vw",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "AlexaBackground",
            "style": "backgroundStyle",
            "backgroundColor": "#303030",
            "backgroundBlur": false,
            "colorOverlay": true
          },
          {
            "type": "AlexaHeader",
            "headerTitle": "${StationData.displayName}",
            "headerSubtitle": "${StationData.format}",
            "headerAttributionImage": "${StationData.images_640x640}",
            "headerDivider": true,
            "headerAttributionPrimacy": false,
            "headerAttributionOpacity": 1
          },
          {
            "type": "Text",
            "text": "Demo 1",
            "paddingLeft": "@marginHorizontal",
            "paddingRight": "@marginHorizontal",
            "paddingTop": "@spacingSmall",
            "textAlignVertical": "center",
            "fontSize": "30dp",
            "maxLines": 4,
            "color": "#ff0000",
            "grow": 1
          },
          {
            "type": "AlexaImage",
            "imageSource": "${StationData.images_640x640}",
            "imageRoundedCorner": true,
            "imageScale": "best-fit",
            "imageAlignment": "center",
            "imageHeight": "50vh",
            "imageAspectRatio": "square",
            "imageBlurredBackground": true
          },         
          {
            "type": "AlexaFooter",
            "style": "footerStyle",
            "hintText": "Here is the Footer"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I already tried to insert the image and the text in one frame with 50% width each, but unfortunately that was not successful.
Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The APL `Container` component uses `column` as direction per default, see [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-container.html). This means that your items are laid out in a column (one below each other).

You'll to create another Container component with `direction: "row"` and add the image and text components to it. Then it is a matter of adjusting `justifyContent` and maybe `alignItems`.